# How do I restrict WebSphere to just localhost requests?

Tags: security, websphere

I'm running WebSphere 8.5.5.15 and I want to restrict it to not serve requests coming from any outside user in my development environment. I only want to serve requests from localhost. I've been looking for a solution but I've only found resources to turn on security/ssl/https.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TCP transport channel configuration *Address include list* or *Host name include list* to accomplish this. These properties are used to control the addresses or hosts that are allowed to make inbound connections.

For more information: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=cpctc-tcp-transport-channel-settings